# Обращение к текущему элементу селектора Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, веб-программирование

Есть группа пар элементов `div.FilterDropdown__body.FilterDropdown__body_opened > div.FilterGroupNewDesign`. Требуется с помощью Jquery установить высоту `div.FilterDropdown__body.FilterDropdown__body_opened` равную высоте `div.FilterGroupNewDesign`. Для этого я пользуюсь оператором

```
$("div.FilterGroupNewDesign").parent.css("height", /*обращение к текущему элементу селектора div.FilterGroupNewDesign*/)
```

Вопрос в том, как обратиться к текущему элементу селектора `div.FilterGroupNewDesign`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$("div.FilterGroupNewDesign").each(function(){
  let $div = $(this);
  $div.parent().css( "height", $div.height() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="FilterDropdown__body FilterDropdown__body_opened">
  <div class="FilterGroupNewDesign">123<br>456</div>
</div>

<div class="FilterDropdown__body FilterDropdown__body_opened">
  <div class="FilterGroupNewDesign">789</div>
</div>
```

Comment: а почему нельзя просто `$("div.FilterGroupNewDesign").parent().css("height", $(this).height())`?

Comment: Потому что this будет равен window